# Trying to implement tabs using native base in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to implement tabs in react native app using native base.
I am getting this error which i don't understand.
undefined is not an object(evaluating 'child.props.heading.props')

this is the code where i am importing the pages.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import {Tabs} from 'native-base';

import TabOne from './TabOne';
import TabTwo from './TabTwo';
//import Head from '../app/Header';
export default class yolo extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <Tabs>
          <TabOne tabLabel='Groups'/>
          <TabTwo tabLabel='Create Group'/>
      </Tabs>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('yolo', () => yolo);
```

this is the code for the page. Both are same

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import{
  Text
} from 'react-native';
export default class TabTwo extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you did not describe the other tab..

Comment: It's looking for a heading props: <Tab heading="Tab1">

Answer (score 1):

i use native base myself. Copy paste this code snippet and check if it works.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import {Tabs} from 'native-base';

import TabOne from './TabOne';
import TabTwo from './TabTwo';
//import Head from '../app/Header';
export default class yolo extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <Tabs>
                <Tab heading="Groups">
                    <TabOne />
                </Tab>
                <Tab heading="Create Group">
                    <TabTwo />
                </Tab>
      </Tabs>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('yolo', () => yolo);
```

Comment: @Avikrit Still facing the same issue? Else please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is because Native base tabs are used as tab bar view. For navigation amongst the tab, you still need to use something like Router-Flux.

Native base tabs will just help you style your tab bar in a more flexible way.

This will help : https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative that gives you more options using the tab navigation in react native.I have tried it and works fine for me. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, as it doesn't answer the question and only provides a link

Answer (score 0):

By official example, you must to put each `Tabs` set inside a `Container` no matter what you used `Container` outside before: http://rawgit.com/GeekyAnts/native-base-docs/v2.2/_book/Components.html#tabs-def-headref

```
return (
    <Container>
        <Header hasTabs />
        <Tabs>
            <Tab heading="Tab1">
                <Tab1 />
            </Tab>
            <Tab heading="Tab2">
                <Tab2 />
            </Tab>
            <Tab heading="Tab3">
                <Tab3 />
            </Tab>
        </Tabs>
    </Container>
);
```

`Header` tag is optional.